# Run javascript once every 12 hours

Tags: javascript, popup

Is there any way I could run a javascript code every 12 hours.
I have a popup script implemented in a website. And I dont want that to popup every time.
I just want it to popup every 12 hours.

Well for this I need to store the IP address of the user in database and check with some programming if he has visited the website within last 12 hours.

Well at least with javascript, is there a way to stop it for a instance of visit. Like if the user closes the popup and navigates away to some other page, the popup should not appear again.

Comment: cookies. Expire it after 12 hours. Check for existance of it before showing popup.

Comment: use a cookie with an expire date after 12 hours. If the cookie is set don't show the popup. Or use localstorage if available (IE8+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

That'll give you an idea of how to use cookies. **If you're already using jQuery** then check out this cookies plugin to make things easier:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Could you please help me with a example.?

Comment: Too busy at the moment I'm afraid, but I'll try to later. Got a link?